# Unable to Loop datagridview and amend DefaultCellStyle.Format to N0

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is populated from an sql query. I would like to format the columns that represent a number to N0 (so they have thousand separators), but the method below is not amending the columns.
When I view these columns in the debugger they have a ValueType of Double.

```
public void DataGridViewFormat(DataGridView dataGrid)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGrid.Columns)
    {
        if (c.DefaultCellStyle.Format == "N")

        {
            c.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N0";
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am populating the datagridview:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(comboBox.Text.Split('|')[0]));
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: have you set a breakpoint and validated that the if-block is ever true?

Comment: Thank you. The block is not ever true. When I change the if statement to test ```c.DefaultCellStyle.Format == ""``` all the columns are hit with the formatting, which is not what I want. Not sure what the right format type is.

Comment: Is it WinForms? Add tag.

Comment: How is the grid populated? Are you using data binding?

Comment: Loop the target columns! Access them by their indices or names. They don't have `.Format == "N"` by default...

Comment: It is WinForms thank you. I've decided to use a list as a parameter to the method, to explicitly hit the columns I want and that's working fine. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I've added in how I am populating the datagridview to the question section.

Comment: You know which columns were requested in `queryString`. You know the types of these columns. So specify the desired format in the DataGridView for the desired columns. | Note: you can use [CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-customize-data-formatting-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) event.